# Facade coming off wooden doors

Tags: wood

[image]

[image]

Facade is peeling off wooden wardrobe doors. Seems to happen more at certain times. Weather related?

In any case how to fix? Wood glue?

Comment: Contact cement/glue.  Probably want to remove the door and work on it in a horizontal position.

Comment: Clean as much of the old glue and any other material out from between the surfaces and remove any dust that doing that might create for a good bond with contact cement. Most such cements would not be good stuff to breathe, either, so have good ventilation!

Answer (score 4):

Don’t use wood glue it will not normally adhere to the laminate.
Rubber cement / contact adhesive is a good method. I have a spray that is great for this it is made for putting sandpaper on sanding disks. But it’s just rubber cement in a spray can.

For Rubber cement contact adhesives to work they need to be applied and let dry until tacky then pressed together.

I suggest the spray in this case so there are no bubbles of adhesive but a thin coat allowed to get tacky then pressed together is how laminate countertops are done.

Once the contact glue , rubber cement is applied it should not come loose again so make sure to align the piece as once stuck it is almost impossible to remove without breaking.

I have laminate rollers to push things together but this size could be done with the palm of your hand just don’t use excessive glue.

Answer (score -1):

It will be hard to stick the laminate panels back on so they are smooth and flush and square, unless you have a press.    A large weight of similar size may work too.  Separate weights would give an uneven finish.

You might be able to use a single board as a spreader and then pile weights on top of that

Either way you would have to unmount the door and lay it flat.

It might be more efficient in terms of time and money to simply replace with a new door.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You should improve this answer because as it stands it is being flagged as low quality and is in danger of being deleted. I would suggest as a minimum if you provide information why a press is required and/or supply additional suggestions as to how the door could be clamped between sturdy straight boards using multiple clamps.

Comment: There's no need whatsoever to replace the door (unless, of course, the OP _wants_ to replace it). Regluing the laminate, per the instructions in Ed Beal's answer, is simple and cost effective.